# Dataclass attribute missing when using explicit __init__ constructor and default_factory parameter in dataclasses.field

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

The following code creates a dataclass `Obj` with an int field `n` with default value 0.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Obj:
    n: int = field(default_factory=int)
    
a = Obj()
print(a.n)
```

```
a.n = 0
```

Now, add an explicit `__init__` constructor:

```py
@dataclass
class Obj:
    n: int = field(default_factory=int)
        
    def __init__(self): # explicit constructor
        pass
```

It now generates this error claiming that the `Obj` object has no attribute named `n`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <module>
      8         pass
     10 a = Obj()
---> 11 print(f'a.n = {a.n}')

AttributeError: 'Obj' object has no attribute 'n'
```

I thought maybe the explicit `__init__` would override whatever `field()` is doing, but if we change from parameter `default_factory` to `default`, it works again:

```py
@dataclass
class Obj:
    n: int = field(default=3)
        
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

```
a.n = 3
```

This behavior appears in both Python 3.8 and 3.10.

Comment: `This module provides a decorator and functions for automatically adding generated special methods such as __init__() and __repr__() to user-defined classes.` so no wonder why you get attribute error when overriding `__init__` again

Comment: Try instead using [Pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/) as it servers dataclasses functionalities and much more than that

Comment: These comments are helpful @sudden_appearance -- but would be more helpful as an answer to the Q. (I would gladly upvote such an answer.)

Comment: @ybressler_simon ok got it

Comment: Note that if, aside from your interesting question (and answers), you really want to perform some initialization of your own, you have the `__post_init__` hook to do it with.  (I like Pydantic myself, but dependencies should be carefully considered).

Comment: @DaveDoty i still don’t got the intention in the question - can you clarify? I am reading it again and again but I didn’t understand what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: I wanted `field()` to provide a default value for the field whether or not I wrote my own custom constructor. One of the nice things about dataclasses is that you can see the fields and default values all in one organized place, instead of having initialization scattered throughout a constructor. I didn't realize that the way `field()` worked was by putting code in the auto-generated constructor. It's confusing to me because you can give default values in other ways while writing a custom constructor (e.g., just writing `= 3` after the field name, or using the parameter `default`).

Comment: Ah yes, that mákes sense now. Yes, the `= 3` is just syntactic sugar for creating a `field` with default value. It’s pretty great that dataclasses allows that shorthand, because it makes it more readable imo. If you look at the source code for dataclasses, what it’s actually doing is converting all assigned values to `Field` objects explicitly, then it also loops over all fields and adds them to the `__init__` páram valúes, so default values get passed to it’s generated constructor method.

Answer (score 7):

`field` doesn't really "do" anything; it just provides information that the `dataclass` decorator uses to define an `__init__` that creates and initializes the `n` attribute. When you define your *own* `__init__` method instead, it's your responsibility to make sure the field is initialized according to the definition provided by `field`. (The same goes for the other methods that `dataclass` would define.)

Comment: I suppose my confusion is that `field()` DOES have an effect when you use `default` instead of `default_factory`, even when providing a custom `__init__`. But I'll chalk this up to some undocumented behavior in dataclasses that probably should not be relied on. Thanks!

Comment: Sort of. `n` isn't really an instance attribute initially; it's a class attribute that implements the descriptor protocol (sort of a `property`, but different). The definition of the descriptor does make use of the `default` value, but there's still no instance attribute named `n` unless `__init__` defines it.

Answer (score 3):

As I told in comments, the default meaning of dataclasses is to generate special methods just by using decorators. Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) say

```
This module provides a decorator and functions for automatically adding generated special methods such as __init__() and __repr__() to user-defined classes.
```

So as far as you are overriding `__init__` method again, you will get an `AttributeError`

Instead try using very popular [Pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/) library, as it serves same functions and features that dataclasses do and serves a lot more powerful things such as validation and custom fields (EmailStr and so on), json parsing and others

#### Edit

The example of similar pydantic model

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Obj(BaseModel):
    n: int = Field(default_factory=int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Obj, self).__init__()
        ...


m1 = Obj()

print(m1.n)  # 0
```

and with default value

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Obj(BaseModel):
    n: int = Field(5)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Obj, self).__init__()
        ...


m1 = Obj()

print(m1.n)  # 5
```

Although it might seem kind of similar, pydantic's `Field` provide much more kwargs for describing the value:

```
def Field(
    default: Any = Undefined,
    *,
    default_factory: Optional[NoArgAnyCallable] = None,
    alias: str = None,
    title: str = None,
    description: str = None,
    exclude: Union['AbstractSetIntStr', 'MappingIntStrAny', Any] = None,
    include: Union['AbstractSetIntStr', 'MappingIntStrAny', Any] = None,
    const: bool = None,
    gt: float = None,
    ge: float = None,
    lt: float = None,
    le: float = None,
    multiple_of: float = None,
    max_digits: int = None,
    decimal_places: int = None,
    min_items: int = None,
    max_items: int = None,
    unique_items: bool = None,
    min_length: int = None,
    max_length: int = None,
    allow_mutation: bool = True,
    regex: str = None,
    discriminator: str = None,
    repr: bool = True,
    **extra: Any,
) -> Any:
```

Comment: What would make this answer _even more helpful_ is an example using Pydantic. (A lot of people are going to come across this answer, it would be great to give them the correct answer + with code as context) :)